Get the nullable property of a column using Laravel Schema
Up until Laravel version 10.x, many queries were supplemented with Doctrine DBAL. Starting from Laravel 11, these have been deprecated.
I could easily get column's nullable property using Doctrine DBAL by calling the Column.getNotNull() function. I know I can run my own SQL query for the information; I just want to make sure there is a native alternative to this function that is no longer usable without Doctrine DBAL.
How can I determine whether a column is nullable (or other properties) using only Schema?

Oh, I got it. We have two functions: Schema.getColumnListing and Schema.getColumns. Well, I didn't notice that at first. The getColumns method returns the table columns along with all their important properties.
Schema::getColumns($tableName);


Result: array of columns
Column's structure
[
  "name" => "columnName"
  "type_name" => "integer"
  "type" => "integer"
  "collation" => null
  "nullable" => false        // here a nullable property
  "default" => null
  "auto_increment" => false
  "comment" => null
  "generation" => null
]


